# Why does a stable trivialization of $T(S^k \times D^l)\oplus \varphi^*(TM)$ induce a bundle map covering $\varphi$?

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $\varphi:S^k \times D^l \to M$ be a smooth map of $(k+l)$-dimensional Manifolds. Let $\epsilon$ denote the trivial bundle.

In our lecture notes we showed that there is a stable trivialization of $T(S^k \times D^l)\oplus \varphi^*(TM)$ and therefore (?) there has to be a bundle map $T(S^k \times D^l)\oplus \epsilon^a\to TM\oplus \epsilon^a$ covering $\varphi$.

But why does this trivialization induce this bundle map? And how does this bundle map look like?

---

Do we have maps of the summands into the whitney sum? Then we could get the following map, which should be the desired map.
$$T(S^k \times D^l)\oplus \epsilon^a \to T(S^k \times D^l)\oplus \varphi^*(TM)\oplus \epsilon^a = \epsilon^{a+b} \to  \varphi^*(TM)\oplus \epsilon^a \to TM\oplus \epsilon^a$$
If not, how do I get this map?